# problem regarding my discord bot coded through jda

Tags: java, eclipse, discord, discord-jda

My bot is stuck printing the output. I check and there was no problem with the logical part as I used the sane logic to make a normal java program. Please help as it is stuck printing the output in discord and I do not know how to solve it.
I also added some unnecessary print functions to find out where the error was. To my surprise, it was just in printing the message which is unusual as I have made bots before and none of them had any errors to just "print" messages.

```
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

public class rpsidnfp {
    public static JDA jda;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws LoginException {
        jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("(my token here)").build();
        core2 core2obj = new core2();
        jda.addEventListener(core2obj);
    }
}
```

The former was my main class.
And below is the core class as it contains all the functions.

```
package pack.rpsidnfp;

import java.util.Random;

//import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;


public class core2 extends ListenerAdapter {
    public static String prefix = "!";
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String input = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        String[] options = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
        Random robj = new Random();
        int rnum = robj.nextInt(options.length);
        System.out.println(rnum);
        String conf = options[rnum];
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(conf);
        System.out.println(conf);
        String same = prefix + conf;
        String win = "congrats, you won!";
        String lose = "lmao, you lost";
        if(input.equals(same)) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("we both kept the same thing");
        }
        else if(input.equals(prefix + options[0])) {
            if(conf.equals(options[1])) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(lose);
            }
            else if(conf.equals(prefix + options[2])) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(win);
            }
        }
        else if(input.equals(prefix + options[1])) {
            if(conf.equals(options[0])) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(win);
            }
            else if(conf.equals(options[2])) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(lose);
            }
        }
        else if(input.equals(prefix + options[2])) {
            if(conf.equals(options[0])) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(lose);
            }
            else if(conf.equals(options[2])) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(win);
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [sendMessage](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#sendMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)) method returns a [MessageAction](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/restaction/MessageAction.html). You need to call `queue()` on that RestAction instance.

Additionally, keep in mind that your bot receives its own messages so you should make sure it ignores those. You can add a `if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return;` to the start of your listener method.

See Also:

- [Troubleshooting Guide: Nothing happens when using X](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19)-Troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-using-x)
- [RestAction Guide](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction)
- [MessageListenerExample](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/development/src/examples/java/MessageListenerExample.java)
- [JDA README](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#restaction)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! I forgot to edit that I added the queue(); command at the end but after that it was looping continuously. But then, I found your reply and it was solved. Once again, thanks a lot for helping me solve this :).